# Best way to count the top 10 most frequent authors in R

Tags: html, r, html-table, rstudio

**Here is my Code**

```
page<-read_html("https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-help/2016-March/date.html")

author<-html_nodes(page, "li i") %>% html_text() %>% trimws()

table(author)
```

**I get the table, but I am trying to count the top ten most frequent authors. What is the best way to do that, preferably with the table function? thanks**

Comment: sort(table(author,decreasing=T))[1:10]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can `sort` and get the first 10 elements with `head`

```
head(sort(table(author), decreasing = TRUE), 10)
```